# how to change position from fixed to absolute and not have the div jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am implementing a sticky behaviour for a div, that works like this
when user scrolls the page, the sidebar on the right scrolls up till it reaches close to the top then it stops while user is still scrolling down sidebar should again start to scroll up when user reaches close to the bottom of page.

What happens is when user reaches close to the bottom I change the position of the sidebar from fixed to absolute and that makes it jump.

Is there way to change a position from fixed to absolute and have it not jump while I do that but continue the scroll up from the same coordinates?

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="border: 0px dashed black; margin-left: 2.933%; height: 832px; osition: relative;">

    <div class="sticky" style="border: 1px dashed red;">
        <div id="map" style="min-height: 350px;"></div>
        <div style="padding: 20px">interesting</div>
        <div style="padding: 20px">interesting</div>
        <div style="padding: 20px">interesting</div>
        <div style="padding: 20px">interesting</div>
        <div style="padding: 20px">interesting</div>
        <div id="last-interesting">last-interesting</div>
    </div>
```

```
var stickyHeaderTop = $('.sticky').offset().top;
if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop-10 ) {
    $('.sticky').css({position: 'fixed', zoom: '1', top: '10px', left:'925px'});
} else {
    $('.sticky').css({position: 'relative', zoom: '1', top: '0px', left: '0px', width:'330px'});
}

if ($('#content-last').visible(true)) {
    // alert('visible');
    console.log($('.sticky').offset().top);
    $('.sticky').css({position: 'absolute', zoom: 'auto', 'z-index': '1', left: '', height: ''});
}
```

I've tried this also

```
$('.sticky').css({position: 'absolute', top: '0' zoom: 'auto', 'z-index': '1', left: '', height: ''});
```

and this

```
$('.sticky').css({position: 'absolute', top: $(window).scrollTop()+'px', zoom: 'auto', 'z-index': '1', left: '', height: ''});
```

but the first one is like not setting top at al, just like in the video, and the second one jumps down to the middle of screen.

Got any ideas how I may solve this issue?

you can see the sticky effect I am after [right here](https://www.yelp.com/search?start=0&l=g:-73.7896728515625,40.86123719133197,-74.19891357421875,40.548920243581556).

Comment: `position: absolute` is setting an elements position "relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element" (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) So maybe making yourself clear how this works might be a good approach. Check all the ancestor elements and find out the one to which your `.sticky` is relatively positioned.

Comment: Placing the div outside everything (so that `<body>` is the only ancestor) might do the trick.

Comment: not directly related, but you have `osition: relative;` in your HTML. missing a "p".

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ actually this might be related considering what I wrote before

Comment: Shouldn't `if ($('#content-last').visible(true)) {` be: `if ($('#content-last:visible')) {`?

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ I updated that but it does not change the behaviour

Comment: @Scott Marcus I am using a jquery plugin for visibility. I was not sure how else to check if div is visible on screen

Comment: @elementzero23 If I place the div so it's directly under the body it will no longer be a sidebar div, I want to keep it there

Comment: @Maxlight but if you use absolute positioning you can position it at the side of the page!?

Comment: true but I yelp.com where I am looking for inspiration did not place their sidebar directly under the body either, I studied their code and notice that instead of setting top, they set bottom to 0, I tried that as well but still experience jumping

Comment: You copied all the styles without knowing how they work.

Comment: I did not copy anything I noticed that they set bottom to 0 and tried that. I have not clue how they have implemented this since I could not find javascript behind the behaviour.

Comment: I have not, I'll give it a try, thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I can show you how to make from `position: static` to `position:fixed`, I think you can use it to what you want to do:

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='body'>

  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <div class='box'>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for `SCSS`

SCSS:

```
.container{
  div{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
  }
}
.body{
  background-color: #3fa142;
  height: 250vh;
  width: 65%;
}
.right{
  padding-top: 70px;
  height: 250vh;
  width: 34%;
  .box{
    height: 34vh;
    background-color: #f66a68;
    width: 150px;
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
boxPosition = $(".box").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var isFixed = $(".box").css("position") === "fixed";
   if($(window).scrollTop() > boxPosition && !isFixed){
            $(".box").css({position:"fixed", top: "0px"});
   }else if($(window).scrollTop() < boxPosition){
        $(".box").css({position:"static"});
   }
})
```

Let me know if you have any questions regarding this solution.

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/mcquintrix/s36qjpu0/)

Comment: Hi I tried the solution and it misses the part where the red box scrolls up when the bottom of the green box is reached, right now it just stays at the top. Is it possible to make it move up when end of green box is visible?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was to use sticky position that is only implemented in some browsers

```
position: -webkit-sticky;  // required for Safari
position: sticky;
top: 0; // required as well.
```

On browsers that is not supported polyfill is used, there is plugin for it 
https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill

To use it just do

```
$('.sticky').Stickyfill();
```

It works perfectly, check the demo here http://wd.dizaina.net/en/scripts/stickyfill/

Comment: Yeah sticky is great, it is still being implemented, it is implemented for this same reason!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the same smooth effect changing absolute to fixed and vice versa. You can only get that by using position sticky.

Comment: Hello, i recommend providing an example so you can prove that your post is a fact for future Stackoverflow users.